# how to manipulate strings with shell-script

Tags: string, shell, filenames

This is what I used:

```
for i in `find some -type f -name *.class`
```

I got:

```
some/folder/subOne/fileOne.class
some/folder/subOne/fileTwo.class
some/other/sub/file.class
```

next, I would like to get rid of the "`some/`" for each value of `$i`. What command can I use? Do I HAVE to save them into a file first?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ i=some/other/sub/file.class
$ echo ${i#some/}
other/sub/file.class
```

Bash has simple string manipulation built in. See also ${i%.class} and the basename and dirname commands.

Answer (score 0):

awk :)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK

**EDIT:** Oh and you can pipe commands together, so the output of the first command acts as the input for the second. Like 'cat example.txt | less' will output the file through a paginator.